# How to use sendmail-jilter for Postfix email header parsing?

Tags: email, filter, postfix-mta

I want to filter e-mail headers received on my Postfix mail receiving server.

I looked on the java implementation of milter protocol and found [sendmail-jilter](http://sendmail-jilter.sourceforge.net/)

This API claims to be java implementation for milter protocol.

The problem is I am novice in milter and don't know how to use this API, any code sample and example in java using this API will greatly reduce my load as it's not available on the parent site.

Thanks in advance.

Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [link](http://www.acme.com/software/sample_milter/) for understanding and implementing a Sendmail Milter, Jilter replicates this functionality.